# Checking duplicate email while editing user profile using php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Checking duplicate email while editing user profile using php
how i can check email is not available in another user profile.

Comment: This depends on your application configuration. Usually you need to query your users table by the email key and check if there's already an existing row. Even better you should set the email as a UNIQUE key in your database. If you need more help, show your code and show your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a select query like so:

```sql
select 1
from users
where email = 'new_email_address@example.com'
and id <> id_of_user_editing_their_profile -- this is the important bit
```

If it returns one or more rows then some other user is using the specified email.